# Mounting a local directory to remote docker container

Tags: python, mount

I have a remote docker container which I pulled and is currently running using:

```
docker pull bamos/openface
docker run -p 9000:9000 -p 8000:8000 -t -i bamos/openface /bin/bash
```

I also have a local directory at

```
/Users/name/Documents/my-project
```

I need to `import openface` from scripts inside `my-project` while developing in `ipython`, but I do not know how to mount `my-project` onto `openface`, or should it be the other way around.

In general, I have been reading the docs here https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume, but am still very confused. I would greatly appreciated it if someone could

1. give the exact commands so that I can import `openface` from `my-project`
2. explain aspects of the command so I am less confused :D

Thank you!

==============================================================
EDIT:

right now I am doing:

```
docker run -v /Users/name/Documents/my-project:/root/my-project -p 9000:9000 -p 8000:8000 -t -i bamos/openface /bin/bash
```

and it seems to be working.

Comment: What folder of your container do you need to be mounted? So, we will mount `/path/to/container/folder` to host folder `/Users/name/Documents/my-project`. What is your `/path/to/container/folder`?

Comment: @Rafael right now I am doing `docker run -v /Users/myname/Documents/my-project:/root/my-project -p 9000:9000 -p 8000:8000 -t -i bamos/openface /bin/bash`, and I can see `my-project` in `:/root/my-project` and it's working. However, I need to install a bunch of packages. Should I install in the `openface` container? Or should I mount my entire /Users/myname drive to `openface` so everything is there?

Comment: You should install the packages at your container. So, when you deploy to a production server, you won't need to copy your `/Users/myname/Documents/my-project` volume. I suggest you check (here)[https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/]. It is a docker compose reference. For now, just check the item 3 (*Add the following content to the Dockerfile.*). It install the required packages via pip. Later, (after you learn Docker Engine) is good to learn Docker Compose (and this link will be more useful).

Comment: The correct link: https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/

Comment: @Rafael as I understand I do not own this container though? Since I did `docker pull bamos/openface`? Or is the `pull` here like `git pull`, and somehow the container is on my local machine, I just don't know here it is?

Comment: @Rafael just to add to my previous comment, I tried `/Users/<username>/.docker/machine/machines/default/ directory` and `/Users/MyUserName/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/Docker.qcow2`, but neither the directory `.docker` nor `Containers` exists on my machine.

Comment: Understood. But you can create your own :). You just have to make your Dockerfile, and define `FROM bamos/openface`. But let's keep it simple. What do you want to do? Do you want to create an image based on bamos/openface? If so, I can make an answer explaining about creating your own image. I am trying to understand what you need to do.

Comment: @Rafael, I am still learning docker so my goals relative to docker are actually not clear. But my overall goals are to (1) develop openface on my machine as if I `pip install`ed it. (3) not have to reinstall everything everytime I close a container.  The project is experimental in nature so there is no clear eye towards deployment. Although I would prerfer to not code myself into a corner, and if Docker is the way to go, I will make a commitment to learn the stuff and deploying this project is a good first step. Could you provide an answer please? Since SO won't let me post more commnents!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I will just point some topics you can study and give thoughts that I think can be useful for you.

As you are still learning, let's go through these topics:

- Using a docker image
- Custom a docker image
- Integrate some docker images

**Using a docker image**

This is what you already know. Run `docker run -v /Users/name/Documents/my-project:/root/my-project -p 9000:9000 -p 8000:8000 -t -i bamos/openface /bin/bash` and start using it. Run some commands and see the capabilities of the image provided.

Use cases (for me):

- Once, I needed test NoSQL Cassandra. I easily run `docker run --name some-cassandra -d cassandra:latest` and it is already working
- I will make an Python/Flask app, so instead of making virtualenv, I prefer Docker.

Not so good for now, but it is interesting to use.

**Custom a docker image**

Instead of using ephemeral images, you can create your own. So, you need to learn about Dockerfile. Here is a simple example:

```
FROM bamos/openface

RUN pip install flask
COPY myentrypoint.sh

CMD ["myentrypoint.sh"]
```

Fast explanation:

- Start your own image from `bamos/openface`
- Run a command that install python package flask
- Copy your entrypoint (you need to create one)
- Run this entrypoint when user use your container

With this image, just save with name `Dockerfile` and run `docker build -t 
chibro2/myopenface .`, and then you have your own image with an extra package.

entrypoint is a default sh command that will start something (for example, a web server). If you have an online instance (AWS, for example) you can run your docker, and it will start your web service. If you tested locally, you should have the same results online. One common problem is testing with different versions (like python3 local, and python2 at the server).

Use cases:

- Make versions of your infrastructure (you have at your git repository all packages required)
- Make an image that will work easily on your server.

Check:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/docker-explained-using-dockerfiles-to-automate-building-of-images
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

**Integrate some docker images**

One thing that I really like at Docker, is the docker compose. You easily work with several docker images that work with each other. An example of docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Fast explanation:

- We create a container db, a postgres database
- We create a webservice, build from Dockerfile (it is implicit in build), and run a server with command `python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`.

*Ps.: Yes, it use the code as a volume, but this something I don't recommend for production, but recommend for development (so, you easily change your code, and don't need to build the image).*

With docker-compose, we easily integrate several projects and start all with a single command: `docker-compose up`

Use cases:

- This is excelent for microservices
- Services discovery is easy
- Simple command for scale (`docker-compose scale web=2` will create 2 instances of your web server).

Check this quickstart: https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/

**Conclusion**

There is too much to learn about docker. I can't give a very good answer on this, but I hope I could help a little.

Possible future steps is to use Docker Machine and Docker Swarm.